# How can I convert IDX/SUB DVD subtitles into a text SRT subtitle file?

Tags: convert, subtitle

I have a pair of .idx/.sub subtitle files with multiple languages and I need to convert them to single-language .srt files because neither Totem nor Gnome Mplayer can show that type of subtitles.

Answer (score 10):

idx/sub are called VobSub file and are bitmap images + timecode that are overlay on top of the video during playback.

A srt file is a simple text file with timecode that is then render on the video.

This means that to be able to convert them to text string you need to do some [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), Optical character recognition. Sadly, most OCR solutions don't support idx/sub.

At this point, the best solution I have for you is called [SubRip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) (see also [official site](http://zuggy.wz.cz/)) and it's Windows software only. It [tends to run well](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2621) in [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine), so you should be able to use it in Ubuntu (without Windows). You can also use [Avidemux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux) according to [this guide](http://members.chello.hu/balla.gyorgy/balla-it/html/articles/20081230-converting_vobsub_subtitles_to_subrip_format_under_linux.html).

Both will present you the bitmap image from the idx/sub, you type what you see and it will build the corresponding srt file. Doom9 has [a nice guide for SubRip](http://www.doom9.org/subrip.htm).

You can also burn in the subtitle to the video file, [Handbrake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handbrake) will be able to do that.

From there, [Doom9](http://www.doom9.org/) and [VideoHelp](http://www.videohelp.com/) are going to be more helpful than AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 6):

The Avidemux way is very handy.

Very good tutorial here: https://archive.flossmanuals.net/avidemux/ch019_extract-dvd-subtitles.html

Works very good for me, if you have more questions, please ask

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/convert_subtitles_from_sub-idx_to_srt.cfm you can use a program called SubResync, part of the VobSub package (Windows).

I tried it with one movie and found that "teaching" the OCR all the slightly different shapes of the letters is pretty time-consuming, and if you make a mistake, you can't correct it! So I would only use this method if (a) the subtitles are really important and it's worth spending the time, or (b) the subtitles are in a simple, consistent font and a given letter looks exactly the same every time it appears.