# Convert Sub/Idx to Srt

Tags: software-recommendation, video

There is a similar question was asked before: [How can I convert IDX/SUB DVD subtitles into a text SRT subtitle file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149798/how-can-i-convert-idx-sub-dvd-subtitles-into-a-text-srt-subtitle-file) more than 6 years ago and the solution is to deal with OCR. There are online tools out there for such conversion, and they just ask to upload the Sub+Idx files and do the job.

I wonder if there is any desktop software for Ubuntu, which can do it offline.

Answer (score 4):

There is an app called [SubtitleEdit](https://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit). It uses tesseract as backend for OCR stuff. I successfully run it on Arch Linux (it's available in repos) so not sure how to install it on Ubuntu, probably you'll need to build it from source.

There is also [vobsub2srt](https://github.com/ruediger/VobSub2SRT). It is command line only tool which also uses tesseract. You can install it from ppa on Ubuntu.

Comment: `vobsub2srt` (I'm using the [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vobsub2srt-git)) worked great for me. Thanks!